# Xcode 7 can't detect the customize plugin class of ios cordova project

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode7, cordova-plugins, xcode7.3

I coded a iOS plugin for cordova project. My project can run well with My Plugin when i put Plugin Class into Compile Resource of Xcode.

But i have a request which must packed My Plugin into **module.framework.**
I added module.framework into Link binary with Library of Xcode and link in Frameworks Search Path (Build setting). =>**My project can't detect my plugin.**

I try call function in module.framework, it's Ok. But run Cordova project has error that **can not found plugin in module.framework**.(Config.xml already added Plugin Class)

If you have any idea, please help me.
Thank so much!

Comment: how did u add plugin into ur project?

Comment: The way same add a library into iOS project(  I added module.framework into Link binary with Library of Xcode and link in Frameworks Search Path (Build setting).)

Comment: if not not wrong u have developed custom plugin for cordova ios right? if yes then u have to install ur ios plugin into ur cordova project via command  line `cordova plugin add <plugin-name>`

Comment: My plugin run well when i put Class into Plugins folder and Compile Resource of Xcode. But when i packed into module.framework -> can not run. I can't use command line because my plugin is module.framework (Library of iOS-> It's my requirement)